# SQL Server Query to Fill Empty Record with null or 0 Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a code in SQL Server Query that list a tabular presentation of sales of a particular tenant in PER YEAR (Column) and PER MONTH (rows) form.

This is the part code which i think is relevant to post

```
SELECT tenantcode
       ,datename(month, date) [month]
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year1  then sales end), 0) as 'Year1'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year2 then sales end), 0) as 'Year2'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year3 then sales end), 0) as 'Year3'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) =  @Year4 then sales end), 0) as 'Year4'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year5 then sales end), 0) as 'Year5'
FROM TenantSales 
GROUP BY  datename(month,date), tenantcode
ORBDER BY   datepart(MM,DATENAME(MONTH, DATE) + '01 2000')
```

Please note that @Year are variables formulated to get the 5 years based on user selection. In this example 2008-2012. The particular tenant started on MAY 2008, so the sales are made available only starting May 2008. The code produce this output. (For illustration)

[image]

What I desire to achieve is to include all the months like this

[image]

When the sales of the tenant starts or available on January onwards, the code works just fine, however in an instance like what I mentioned, it does not.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to include all months, but are running a query against data which does not contain all months. You will need to join to another table containing all months:

```
SELECT tenants.tenantcode
       ,months.monthname
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(t.DATE) = @Year1  then sales end), 0) as 'Year1'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(t.DATE) = @Year2 then sales end), 0) as 'Year2'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(t.DATE) = @Year3 then sales end), 0) as 'Year3'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(t.DATE) =  @Year4 then sales end), 0) as 'Year4'
       ,isnull(sum(case when year(t.DATE) = @Year5 then sales end), 0) as 'Year5'
FROM 
(
SELECT
    Number
    ,DATENAME(MONTH, '2015-' + CAST(Number as varchar(2)) + '-1') monthname
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 12
) months

CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT tenantcode
    FROM TenantSales
) tenants    

LEFT JOIN TenantSales t
ON months.monthname = datename(month,t.date)
AND tenants.tenantcode = t.tenantcode

GROUP BY  months.monthname, months.number, tenants.tenantcode
ORDER BY   months.number
```

Month table generation taken from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/697f4ee6-35d1-403d-a9f7-caecaf1ba479/all-monthnames-and-month-numbers-in-sql-server

Comment: Try my edit, this will cross join all months to all tenants and then pull data through for each tenant and month where available

Comment: This work, I have just adjusted some to achieve my desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of all months.  For a single tenant (as asked in the question), you can do:

```
with months as (
      select cast('2015-01-01' as date) as d
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, months.d)
      from months
      where months.d < cast('2015-12-01' as date)
     )
SELECT tenantcode,
       datename(m.d, date) [month],
       isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year1  then sales end), 0) as Year1,
       isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year2 then sales end), 0) as Year2,
       isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year3 then sales end), 0) as Year3,
       isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year4 then sales end), 0) as Year4,
       isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year5 then sales end), 0) as Year5
FROM months m LEFT JOIN
     TenantSales CROSS JOIN
     ON month(date) = month(m.d)
GROUP BY datename(month, m.d), tenantcode
ORBDER BY month(m.d);
```

Note that you should only use single quotes for string and date names.  You should not use single quotes for column aliases, because this can lead to confusion.

Comment: an error like a multi-part identifier on d.d @Gordon

Comment: Been trying this and do some workaround but it doesn't work still :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
;WITH months(d) as
(
  SELECT dateadd(m, x, 0)
  FROM (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) x(x)
)
SELECT 
  tenantcode,
  datename(month, m.d) [month],
  isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year1  then sales end), 0) as Year1,
  isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year2 then sales end), 0) as Year2,
  isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year3 then sales end), 0) as Year3,
  isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year4 then sales end), 0) as Year4,
  isnull(sum(case when year(DATE) = @Year5 then sales end), 0) as Year5
FROM
  months m
LEFT JOIN
  TenantSales ts
ON
  month(date) = month(m.d)
GROUP BY
  datename(month, m.d),m.d, tenantcode
ORDER BY
  m.d
```

Comment: same result with the previous answers...  but doing some workaround by including cross join, this would work. So I would vote this as useful.